# Ajax result used as mysql query constraint

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm displaying some database data every 60 seconds using ajax like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        function getData(){
           $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'data.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#output').html(data);
            });
        }

        getData();
        setInterval(function () { getData();  }, 60000);  // it will refresh your data every 1 sec

    });
```

The `data.php` file has a query something like :

```
$sql = "select * from orders where time > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) ORDER BY id DESC";
```

**How can I record the last interval retrieved by ajax and pass it in the query so it only shows records between previous ajax result + 60 seconds?**

I am worrying that it might omit some records if there is a delay somewhere.

Comment: Assuming you have an incrementing ID field could store last ID sent in session and use that for next query

Comment: How can I access the ajax success data return in php? In other words how do I store the last id as a session from ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing data from php to ajax in json format:

```
function getData() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: 'data.php',
                            data: {lastID: lastID},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {
                                lastID = data[0].id;
                                console.log(lastID);
                                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                    var $tr = $('<tr class="page-break">').append(
                                            $('<td>').text(item.id),
                                            $('<td>').text(item.name),
                                            $('<td>').text(item.details)
                                            ).appendTo('#output');
                                });

                                function isEmpty(el) {
                                    return !$.trim(el.html());
                                }
                                if (!isEmpty($('#output'))) {
                                    window.print();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
```

And in php :

```
$lastID = $_GET['lastID'];
$sql = "select * from orders where id > ".$lastID." ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

First set a parameter to use to fetch the data via the get method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function getData(){
           $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'data.php',
                data:"req=req",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#output').html(data);
            });
        }

        getData();
        setInterval(function () { getData();  }, 60000);  // it will refresh your data every 1 sec

    });
```

and set the php to fetch the data with the array.

```
if ($_GET['req']){
    $sql = "select * from orders where time > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) ORDER BY id DESC";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I add in the req parameter the latest id from the sql query?

Comment: I'm sorry but didn't actually got you @Victordb

Comment: I am trying somehow to record the privous interval of the sql query to be sure I am not repeating nor omiting any records. As user @charlietfl metioned I could store the last id but I can't figure out how. I don't know how to retrieve last id from the ajax success and pass it in data as a variable so I can use it in php

Comment: I even tried to pass the sql query data to ajax as json but still I don't know how to retrive last row[id]

Comment: @Victordb you want to obtain the id of the product? see the edit